# How to get the return code from cccheckout task in ant

Tags: ant, clearcase

Im trying to write a logic that depends on the success or failure of cccheckout command. Is there something similar to returnProperty attribute as in exec task?

Thanks,
Aarthi

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [CCCheckout documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/clearcase.html#cccheckout), I would rather use the exception mechanism to process any failure.

```
failonerr
```

> Throw an exception if the command fails. Default is true.
>   Since ant 1.6.1

In ant, that means you can separate your ant process in two (one if no failure, one one exception), using the **[ant trycatch task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're asking that question because of cleartool.exe behaves strangly
sometimes, means it returns RC -1 even if no real error occured.
Means using `cccheckout` with `failonerr="true"` would sometimes cause an unneccessary `Build failed`
as any RC != 0 is handled as error by exec task.
But you might use the `<exec>` task directly with executable cleartool.exe and set attribute

- resultproperty to make the RC available as property
- outputproperty to make stdout available as property
- errorproperty to make stderr available as property

for further processing, i.e. use condition task to check those properties..
Some try/catch/finally feature provided by Ant addons like :

- [AntContrib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/)
- [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)

might come in handy, as VonC already mentioned.
If it gets more complicated afterwards use [Groovy ant task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) or script task.